# How to do elegant error handling in Python

Tags: python

I'm scraping Linkedin using Selenium. This a very brittle task and exceptions are raised often. I want to find an elegant way to handle errors. The internet has the usual try catch but its clunky... See the code below:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(job))
    job_title = job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "base-search-card__title").text
    company = job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "base-search-card__subtitle").text
    location = job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "job-search-card__location").text
except :
    print("Boom Boom")
```

If any of the `find_element` methods throws the `expect` part is run and the code in the try wont execute further. I'd like a scenario where if one fails the except wouldn't be hit i.e. if it fails I can return an empty string. I can wrap everything in a function and do something like this:

```
def extract_job_title(job):
    try:
        return job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "base-search-card__title").text
    except:
        return ""
```

and have:

```
 job_title = extract_job_title(job)
```

but that is also clunky... I want something like I would have in Swift. Something like this:

```
let job_title = try? job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "base-search-card__title").text ?? ""
```

Does something similar to Swift exist and if not can anyone else see a way of making things "nicer" other than using functions?

Comment: Make a more reusable function…? `def extract(job, class_): try return job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_).text except: return None`…?

Comment: PEP 505 sketched a null-coalescing set of operators for Python, https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/, but it hasn’t made its way into the language yet. How about moving the text extraction and exception handling in a `def` that returns `None` on error?

Comment: IMHO, the approach with the function seems fine. You can let the function accept the class name you're looking for and write code like: `job_title = try_find_element(job, "base-search-card__title")`. Here, `try_find_element` is basically your `extract_job_title`, but generalized to extracting other classes.

Comment: Don't just blindly add `try` statements to your code: what exception do you expect to be raised? If an exception *is* raised, can your script continue without `job_title` et al. being set simply because you printed an error message?

Comment: Maybe invert the logic? Find all elements with a wider query, then iterate through them, and extract their values based on the class name? Pseudocode: `cls = {'base-search-card__title': 'title', ...}` `for el in job.find(...): data[cls[el.class_name]] = el.text`

Comment: @deceze your route is looking the best. Alas, I wanted something more "swift" like but your approach will have to do. Can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you have a lot of very repetitive code with only small differences, you can probably extract that into a function or loop. E.g.:

```
searches = {'title': 'base-search-card__title', ...}
data = {}

for item, cls in searches.items():
    try:
        data[item] = job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, cls).text
    except:
        pass
```

This would also extract data into one dict, which seems more logical than a bunch of separate variables.

Alternatively, extracted into a function:

```
def get(job, cls):
    try:
        return job.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, cls).text
    except:
        return None

job_title = get(job, 'base-search-card__title')
```

Note that you should intercept a *specific* exception in `except`, not *any and all* exceptions.

Alternatively, turn the entire thing on its head and only evaluate the elements that actually exist, and sort them into the right bins. Something along the lines of:

```
classes = {'base-search-card__title': 'title', ...}
data = {}

for elem in job.some_broader_find_query():
    data[classes[elem.class_name]] = elem.text
```